# updatestatebykey - Pyspark - Spark streaming

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming

I am new to spark streaming. Trying to understand the importance of UpdateStateByKey operation? what is the use of it? What is the necessity to store arbitary state? How it works?

Answer (score 2):

The `updateStateByKey` method allows you to create state information based on data coming from the stream.

For example - if you have a weather sensors that are sending current status (like wind speed, temperature) for a given sensor_id in format `(sensor_id, (timestamp, values))`, you can use updateStateByKey to build a stream that represents current weather state across sensors, like `[(sensor_1, current_weather_data), (sensor_2, current_weather_data)]`.

Then you can join the stream with other data and even if sensor didn't send its information in last window, state will still contain last value. I used this method in [this notebook](https://github.com/szczeles/public-speaking/blob/pydata2017/notebooks/spark-streaming.ipynb).